# Compile GCC with Code Sourcery

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, arm, beagleboard

Is it possible to compile native GCC for ARM (host == target == ARM) using Code Sourcery G++?
If it is not possible, could I use crosstool-NG to build the cross-compile and then using this one for compiling the native ARM GCC?

Thank you,

---

Edit: as to why: I'm creating my own distro for [beagleboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_Board)...

Comment: I've got to ask, why would you want to run GCC on ARM?

Comment: You may have better luck on chiphacker.com (uC SO).  I do think it will be terribly slow though. The compilation on an ARM host would be unbearably slow IMO.

Answer (score 2):

CodeSourcery provides prebuilt toolchains only for Linux/x86 and Windows (see "Host System Requirements" [here](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/portal/datasheet?target_arch=ARM&target_os=EABI)). If you want a native ARM-hosted toolchain, you should be able to build one using a cross-compiler. If you want a prebuilt one, you can try some of the existing ARM distros such as [Debian-arm](http://www.debian.org/ports/arm/), or [Aboriginal Linux](http://impactlinux.com/fwl/) (it's made to be run in QEMU but you can probably extract the compiler from it and run natively).

Answer (score 1):

Tiny C Compiler runs decently natively on the kindle 3.
Find it on the mobileread forums compiled for native use.

Code sourcery toolchain works for simple comilation via "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc foo.c" IIRC with no effort. creating native arms. Crosstools-ng as well but neither natively AIUI.

I looked into http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_about_buildroot
for a more comprehensive solution.

There are some options in there for what you require IIRC using x-compile to make the compiler but Crosstools is the more robust chain I had trouble with codesourcery doing true static build. HTH

Answer (score -1):

better off to use [openembedded](http://wiki.openembedded.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer to start from scratch. If I want to understand something I think it's better to avoid automated tools (IMHO)