# Cross compiling gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

Im trying to get gcc running on my Kindle 3.  I have a native terminal and ssh working, and I found that the Sourcery G++ toolchain for arm eabi linux produces working binaries, so it seems like I should be able to just configure gcc to build using arm-none-eabi-gcc and compile it, but Im obviously misunderstanding something...  When I configure with --target=arm-none-eabi --host=arm-none-eabi and run make, it compiles using gcc, not arm-none-eabi-gcc. Unless theres some pre-compilation phase that uses gcc?  I havent gotten all the way through the build yet, since Ive had other errors im working through, but I dont want to waste all this time if im configuring something wrong in the beginning.  I found this question, [Compile GCC with Code Sourcery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028426/compile-gcc-with-code-sourcery) where the op seems to want the same thing, but it was never answered...  Also, Ive run into problems when compiling lua with the sourcery compiler, it seems to be using a different version of GLIBC, which I assume will be a problem.  Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

/pathToStuffifNotPathed/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ foo.c

Should you not invoke the compiler via it's tool-chain invocation? I believe so.