# How to cross compile a toolchain to an ARMv5 platform?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am not looking to setup a toolchain to cross compile on an x86 host to an ARMv5 target (I already have that and it's working), but a toolchain to compile on an ARMv5 platform to an ARMv5 target(itself). I know I can always just cross compile all my needed applications, but I want to have a compiler run on the system so I will have a good idea of how to do the same for other boards like the Rasberry Pi and Beaglebone, and because it just seems pretty cool.

I have looked into crosstool-ng but as I understand it seems to only work for an x86 host to various targets, instead of various hosts for various targets.

Is there any recommended workflow for this? I was thinking of seeing how the people who handle distributions for boards like the Beaglebone do it, but I can't seem to find any information on that, are they using some proprietary solution?

The toolchain in question is [this one](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/release2795?) from Sourcery CodeBench Lite which includes the source, but it seems that just running this through the already compiled cross compiler doesn't work.

I found some related questions but it seems that none of them got it going all the way, is there a guide for this out there somewhere? For all of you googling this like I am, and if this were to pop up in your results, here are some of the related questions:

[Cross compile native gcc for arm with crosstool-ng, have toolchain, which architecture deps, and which build, host, and target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298163/cross-compile-native-gcc-for-arm-with-crosstool-ng-have-toolchain-which-archit)

[how to change the host type for a 'Canadian cross' compilation of GCC with crosstool-NG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866367/how-to-change-the-host-type-for-a-canadian-cross-compilation-of-gcc-with-cross/)

[Cross compiling gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181302/cross-compiling-gcc)

[Compile GCC with Code Sourcery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028426/compile-gcc-with-code-sourcery)

[compiling native GCC for arm using cross-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663684/compiling-native-gcc-for-arm-using-cross-compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this myself after a ton of futzing around with libraries and toolchains.

You need to first setup a cross compiler to compile ARMv5 executables for the ARM926J CPU. Why ARMv5 and ARM926J? Because I am using the SAM9N12 which utilizes the ARM926J code (J for Jazelle which runs a native JVM), with that core being an ARMv5 architecture.

You can get the cross compiler either from ARM's [launchpad based GCC repo](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) or make one yourself using Crosstools-NG. Using Crosstools-NG is recommended because you can use your own standard C library (GNU's version is monstrous compared to uClib or musl).

Lastly, you need to use your cross compiler to make a native ARM compiler. Normally, you would be able to do this with Crosstools-NG but the `cross-native` option is not implemented, so you have to do what is called a `Canadian-Build` which works just fine but does some redundant steps.

Since this question specified only for an idea of what general workflow to use, I will leave this as is and refer you to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201599/how-to-use-candian-in-crosstools-ng-in-a-cross-native-fashion-to-get-gcc-on-an-a) asking specifically how to use `Canadian-Build` with Crosstools-NG considering `Cross-Native` is not implemented yet.