# gcc ON arm/android

Tags: android, gcc, arm, android-3.0-honeycomb, transformer-model

I just got a EEE pad transformer. Like any hardware I own I'd like to have a C compiler on it.   I know I can cross compile, but I'd like to do development ON the device itself. I've searched google and all I can seem to find are pages on how to build an arm toolchain for x86/64 Linux. Thoughts?

Comment: Here's a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028426/compile-gcc-with-code-sourcery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process of building gcc (et al.) to run on your target should be similar to building a cross-compiler, excepting that you will:

- need to have an ARM cross compiler that runs on your, for example, x86 machine. So the results of your googleing are still useful.
- use the `--host` option to specify your ARM platform when running `configure` for all of the parts of your toolchain.

Comment: I figured I could do this... I guess I was more hoping that I'd find some binaries and save myself a lot of headache :-) I guess I will have to build something for arm. Maybe tcc (http://bellard.org/tcc/) can cross compile itself. That has to be far easier than gcc...

Comment: One choice you will have to make is if you want to try to build gcc et all against android's own bionic libc, or against a more standard libc (and either statically link or stash the shared libs somewhere).  You might also want to check into some of the projects to run unbuntu or debian on android tablets.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept an answer. I never ended up getting a solution to this, but I read that there were some issues about using C/C++ on android anyway.

Comment: @Tim were you able to cross-compile tcc in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked about this in June, 2011, (or maybe starting right around that same time) there's something that does EXACTLY what you want called "Terminal-IDE." This is a much better answer than the one you checked off as correct because it doesn't rely upon cross-compilation as the checked answer does.

Terminal-IDE is an Integrated Development Environment that runs ON your Android device (just as you asked about), and has both a C compiler and Java (of course).

There's a [Terminal-IDE web site](http://Terminal-IDE.com/) with a more in-depth description and links to other resources.

**NOTE: Since I wrote this reply, the author of Terminal-IDE has stopped supporting it.**