# Turbo-C++ under DosBox image manipulation library?

Tags: c++, dos, dosbox

Is there any image manipulation (jpg, png or bmp I dont care) library for MS-DOS wich works under DosBox for Android with Turbo-C++?

I want to do a small old-school game and right now this is the only setup I've got to program as my laptop is screwed and Im not going to buy another anytime soom.

The thing is that the Turbo-C++'s graphic manipulation library is enough to do some kinda-decent user interfaces, but I need to use sprites (drawing circles and rectangles is not exactly what I need).

Is there any library? I know MS-DOS is kinda dead, but you gotta use what you have IMO.

And if no, what could I do to display images on screen?, I guess setting the pixels one by one loaded from a bmp could work but seems pretty inefficient and tedious to do.

Any ideas?,
Thanks.

Comment: if you're running dosbox and can access internet to post this then why can't you download a newer compiler/IDE

Comment: Im on an android device. And as far as I know there hasnt been a new compiler or IDE for DOS in quite a while!

Comment: why not? There was [gcc for android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1645182) long time ago. In fact any platform that gcc support can have a gcc compiler since it's self compile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852187/how-to-compile-gcc-for-android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid

Answer (score 1):

[Allegro](https://www.allegro.cc/) is the best general-purpose games & graphics library I know of for DOS. It won't work with Turbo, but it will work with [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/), which is free (it's a build of GCC and related tools for DOS). If you use DJGPP with [RHIDE](http://www.rhide.com/), development feels a lot like Turbo.

Comment: The problem is the library runs in protected mode not dos real mode. He is looking for a real-mode library.

Comment: @XiaogeSu there's no evidence of that in the question. DOSBox runs 386 code just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll try to set it up. Been reading on google that using DJGPP under DosBox is quite difficult tho :s