# How to solve gcc compilation error when installing Python in Termux

Tags: python, gcc, termux

I have error this when i install python on termux
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZuj2.png)

Comment: Please edit your post so that it doesn't contain an [image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

It is [`GCC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) incompatibility. Or it is outdated.

Try to search for solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800331/getrandom-syscall-in-c-not-found) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852187/how-to-compile-gcc-for-android)

Also looks like [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid&hl=en&gl=US) is GCC plugin for Android. Maybe it will help.

Also you may try to install older versions of python