# Compile GCC To Run On Android with NDK Standalone Toolchain

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

I'm running the Android NDK standalone toolchain installed on CentOS and built with the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script using android-14 and ARM GCC 4.7 compiler.

I'd like to build GCC to run in the KBOX environment on my NookHD which has CM installed, using the Android standalone toolchain.  I'd like to use make with the configure scripts instead of Android's ndk-build if possible, because I've put effort into using them, but I'm open to switching to ndk-build.

I've tried several methods, all of which have failed, mostly because I'm working with instructions/recommendations I've pieced together from [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852187/how-to-compile-gcc-for-android) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380846/gcc-on-arm-android) and [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028426/compile-gcc-with-code-sourcery) I've [found](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started:installation:android).

My question(s):

1. Is what I'm trying to do possible?
2. If yes, is there a set of instructions/help files...even a rough outline...of how to accomplish this?

**NOTE:**  I am aware that there are IDE apps in Google Play.  I also know that KBOX has a downloadable Debian package of GCC. I'd still like to build GCC for my environment for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Boone's kbox2 has now got a gcc .deb package. BTW i am also trying to set up a full blown development tool chain on the android phone itself. Got both gcc and make from the kbox2 website. But still not sure if they produce binaries which work with bionic. basic hello world app works though.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond.  From my original post:  _I also know that KBOX has a downloadable Debian package of GCC. I'd still like to build GCC for my environment for various reasons_.  Keep me updated on your progress for the development toolchain...I'll let you know if I get anything up and running.